# Get device orientation without knowing Context

Tags: java, android, orientation

I'm using following method to determine current orientation

```
  public boolean isPortrait() {
    int orientation = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    return orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
  }
```

And now I want to move this method to separate class and make them static to be able to access it with following syntax `Orientation.isPortait`. The problem is `Context` that I need to use to determine orientation. Is there any way to get device orientation without `Context`, `Activity`, etc?

**UPDATE:**

All I need is simplify my code and make it shorter. That's why I don't want to use or pass in `Context` at all.

Comment: Ok, you want be different. Most of us, when we have not a context and we need one, we provide it at class constructor. The android SDK is constantly doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass Context into isPortrait():

```
public boolean isPortrait(final Context context) {
    int orientation = context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    return orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
}
```

Then just pass the context to isPortrait():

```
Orientation.isPortrait(this);  //this or whatever context you have
```

Comment: Thx, but it is not suitable for me. Some my classes do not have Context at all.